# Obtener cada string de cada lista

Tags: vb.net, lista

De un archivo de texto con varios strings los transformo a una lista y necesito comparar cada palabra para saber si los elementos de esa lista coinciden con los elementos de otra lista algo así como un analizador léxico.

El problema esta en que cuando trato de llamar un foreach string no puedo capturarlo.

```
    Dim ruta = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "Pequeno.txt"
    Dim rutaRes = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "Reservadas.txt"
    Dim rutaOP = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "Operadores.txt"

    Dim names1 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ruta)
    Dim names2 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(rutaOP)
    Dim names3 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(rutaOP)


    For Each Email As String In names1
        Dim queryS = Email.Except(names2)
    Next

    Dim Query1 = names1.Except(names2)
    Dim Query2 = names1.Except(names2)

    Dim querRes = Query1.Except(names1)
    Dim querOp = Query1.Except(names1)
```

Comment: La verdad es que no estoy muy seguro de entenderte, creo que deberías explicar un poco mejor. Pero me parece intuir que lo que buscas es [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gracias, básicamente estoy tratando obtener todos los strings entre cada lista y compararlos entre si.

Ejemplo: 
VALOR LISTA1: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_report.Programs))
VALOR LISTA2:  if

entonces en el for each solo quiero analizar cada string de mi lista 1 para comprarlo con la lista 2

Comment: Intenta crear un [mcve] para que entendamos mejor,con ejemplos de las cadenas de entrada y cual sería la salida esperada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no mal te entiendo y con unas pequeñas correcciones tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
Dim ruta = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Pequeno.txt"
Dim rutaRes =My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop &"\Reservadas.txt"
Dim rutaOP = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop &"\Operadores.txt"

Dim names1 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ruta)
Dim names2 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(rutaRes)
Dim names3 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(rutaOP)

Dim intersect As IEnumerable(Of String) = names1.Intersect(names2)
Dim Duplicados As New Text.StringBuilder

For Each Email In intersect
    Duplicados.AppendLine(Email)
Next
```

en los archivos Pequeno tengo este texto:
euro
dollar
peso
sol
bolivar
tolar
manat
libra
corona
rublo

y en Reservadas:
corona
tolar
peso
rublo
euro

el resultados de los duplicados es:
euro
peso
tolar
corona
rublo